# Ace Editor Long Text Wrap in the Annotation

Tags: ace-editor

I am trying display long text via annotation of ace_editor. Icon for displaying annotation is the in the gutter_cell. My question is:

What is the best way to wrap text so that all text is visible?

I have tried using html but no success.

---

[image]

---

```
this.currentEditor.session.setAnnotations([{
      row: this.currentLine - 1,
      column: 0,
      text: message, //<---- very long text
      type: "info"
}]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try adding css like this

```
.ace_tooltip {
    max-width:50px;
    word-wrap:break-word!important;
    white-space: pre-wrap!important;
}
```